# Grunt-template not working as expected

Tags: gruntjs

I try to create `config.js`file with `grunt-template` module however it didn't create any file as expected.

I have installed grunt-template `npm install grunt-template --save-dev`

When I run `grunt build` I expect to create a config file with proper content which is set in template config. I have added gruntfile, config.js.tpl and grunt build outcome below. What would be the problem?

**Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({

....

'template': {
            'config': {
                'options': {
                    'data': {
                        'backend': '127.0.0.1:8000'
                    }
                }
            },
            'files': {
                'config.js': ['config.js.tpl']
            }
        }
}

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-template');
grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'template'

]);

}
```

**config.js.tpl**

```
angular.module('report-constants',[])
    .constant('env', {
        'backend': ''
    });
```

**grunt build result**

Execution Time (2015-01-14 11:33:59 UTC)
loading tasks    4ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 44%
template:config  3ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 33%
template:files   1ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 11%
Total 9ms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`files` and `options` should be under `config` target of the **template** task , try the following code

```
 template: {
     config: {
         options: {
             data: {
                 'backend': '127.0.0.1:8000'
             }
         },
         files: {
             'config.js': ['config.js.tpl']
         }
    }
}
```

Also in config.js.tpl , refer to the `backend` variable that you define in `config` target

```
angular.module('report-constants',[])
  .constant('env', {
    'backend': '<%= backend %>'
});
```